# Problems extracting a .tgz with PHP

Tags: php, unix, exec, tar

I have written the following to download a .tgz and extract it to a specified location. It is downloading successfully but not extracting the files. Personally I can not see the problem here:

```
// Delete old zip
$myFile = "file.seam?fileName=images.tgz";
unlink($myFile);

// Get new zip
$url = "http://shop.x.co.uk/file.seam?fileName=images.tgz";
$fh = fopen(basename($url), "wb");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Extract 
exec('gtar --keep-newer-files -xzf file.seam?fileName=images.tgz --strip-components=2 -C /home/topgoth/public_html/getimages/images/');
```

Comment: do the downloaded files exist in the file system? do they have the proper access rights? which error messages are you getting? does the extraction command work from the command line?

Comment: Yes files are being downloaded but they are large (150MB) and I just received an Internal Server Error when the download was only ~50% complete, the download continued (I was able to monitor it via FTP) but I assume it never extracted because of the Internal Server Error?

Comment: what is the name under which the file resides in the file system? your `gtar`command contains a shell metachar (namely `?` as in `file.seam?fileName=images.tgz`). try to escape the `?` with `\?`  or use curl's `-o`/`--output` option to specify a target filename of your choice

Comment: @collapsar When I visit the link and download the file in the browser it downloads as `images.tgz` but when downloaded by the system it is named `file.seam?fileName=images.tgz`. `file.seam?fileName=` is part of the URL that links to the download. Could you give an example of how to escape `?` I am unfamiliar with this

Comment: i'd advise to call curl using the `-o` option. you may also rename the downloaded file (eg. `mv *images.tgz images.tgz`). the escaped original command would be `gtar --keep-newer-files -xzf file.seam\?fileName=images.tgz ...`. another alternative qould be to quote the file name (without escaped chars!) using single quotes: `gtar --keep-newer-files -xzf 'file.seam?fileName=images.tgz' ...`.

Comment: Thank you, removing the `?` worked